# Ruby: storing a value at inclusion time

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-variables

In a Ruby class, I'd like to store the value of a variable at the time it includes a given module. Below is a contrived example:

```
module M
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      @@inclusion_time = Time.now

      def included_at
        @@inclusion_time
      end
    end
  end
end

class A
  include M
end

sleep 3

class B
  include M
end

sleep 3

class C
  include M
end

a = A.new
b = B.new
c = C.new

puts a.included_at
puts b.included_at
puts c.included_at
```

I've tried this any number of ways (attr_accessor, set_constant, etc,) but the end result is always the same. All of the classes have whatever value was set last.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module M
  def self.included _
    @inclusion_time = Time.now
  end
  def included_at
    self.class.instance_eval{@inclusion_time}
  end
end
```

Comment: When I replace SO's module M with yours, `A.new.included_at` returns nil (same for B and C, of course), whereas `def self.included(klass) klass.instance_variable_set(:@inclusion_time, Time.now) end` gives the desired result. Note that, within `self.included`, self equals M.